# Robot Framework - Get variable

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to get variable value from *report.xml* file using publicAPI. This is how report looks like:

[image: report.xml]

It has a variable **Var** to which a **Test** value is assigned.

I have created simple REST API to run tests:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

from robot import run
from robot import run_cli

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def runRobot():
 robotName = request.args.get('robot')
 robotName = robotName + '.robot'
 rc = run(robotName)
 return str(rc)
```

I would like to return value of **Var** variable instead of execution code. I can't find a matching function in [documentation](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that meets my requirements

Is it even possible to do?

Comment: There are certainly ways to achieve this, but before that, what is your purpose? You want a custom return value for the test execution?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I could imagine for this situation is a custom metadata that you could set to whatever value you want using the [Set Suite Metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Metadata) keyword.

Then you can create a small [ResultVisitor](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.result.html?highlight=ResultVisitor#example) to retrieve the needed metadata. I am using Robot Framework 3.1.2 for the example below.

Example (SO.robot):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Set Suite Metadata    My Return Value    My VALUE    append=True    top=True
```

The Python file calling Robot CLI and the ResultVisitor:

```
from robot import run_cli
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor

class ReturnValueFetcher(ResultVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.custom_rc = None

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        try:
            self.custom_rc = suite.metadata["My Return Value"]
        except KeyError:
            self.custom_rc = 'Undefined' # error, False, exception, log error, etc.
        
        # Only visit the top suite
        return False

# Run robot, exit=False is needed so the script won't be terminated here
rc = run_cli(['SO.robot'], exit=False)

# Instantiate result visitor
retval = ReturnValueFetcher()

# Parse execution result using robot API
# assuming the output.xml is in the same folder as the Python script
result = ExecutionResult("./output.xml")

# Visit the top level suite to retrive needed metadata
result.visit(retval)

# Print return values
print(f"normal rc:{rc} - custom_rc:{retval.custom_rc}")
```

Your custom return value will be clearly visible in your log.html and report.html files as well.

[image]

This is the console output:

[image]